# How do you properly clear a json_encode error state?

Tags: php, json, php-5.6, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

I am using a PHP 5.6.40 development environment. Many of my classes implement `JsonSerializable`. The `jsonSerialize` method of one of these classes uses `json_decode`, since the value of one of its data members may or may not be encoded as JSON. The problem is that after calling `json_decode` on a data member whose value is just a plain string, the `json_encode` fails.

Here is an example:

```
class JsonSerializableClass implements JsonSerializable
{
    private $dataMember;

    public function __construct($dataMember)
    {
        $this->dataMember = $dataMember;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $decodedDataMember = json_decode($this->dataMember, 1);

        if ($decodedDataMember && $decodedDataMember['jsonDataMember'])
        {
            return $decodedDataMember['jsonDataMember'];
        }

        // json_encode(''); This keeps json_encode from failing, but I'm looking for a different solution.

        return $this->dataMember;
    }
}

// This works
$test1 = new JsonSerializableClass(json_encode(array(
        'jsonDataMember' => 'plain string'
)));
var_export(json_encode($test1));

// This fails
$test2 = new JsonSerializableClass('plain string');
var_export(json_encode($test2));
```

This is fixed by adding a call to `json_encode` in the jsonSerialize method after the failed json_decode; however, another developer may not immediately realize what that accomplishes. Of course I would comment my reasoning for doing it, but I'm looking for a more clear solution. Is there error state data that json functions rely on that is being cleared by a successful `json_encode`? If so, is there a way to clearly reset that error state data, like `clear_json_error_state`?

I'm sorry if my explanation is hard to understand; it was difficult for me to explain. Please ask me for any clarification you need.

Comment: why not do a try, catch inside your function with json_encode? why rely on json_encode outside the function? return a string regardless of your input. You can also add checks for types if you are not sure that it will always be a string and/or json

Comment: A failed ```json_decode``` does not throw an error; it returns false. The last error can be retrieved using ```json_last_error``` and the message can be retrieved using ```json_last_error_msg```. The outer ```json_encode``` is encoding a lot of data, not just one of these records. The value being passed to ```json_decode``` is always a string. I just don't know if it's valid json until after putting it through ```json_decode```.

Comment: What error state are you referring to? I tried your script, it echoed `"plain string"` twice. But this was in PHP 7, is it different in PHP 5?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. My development machine uses PHP 7.3.9. This code works just fine in that environment. The production environment uses PHP 5.6.40, where this code fails. The second ```echo``` may not print anything visible on the screen. If I were to use ```var_export``` instead, then it should display ```NULL```. I will update the description.

Comment: I think this is just a bug in PHP, and it was fixed in PHP 7. I don't think there's any direct access to whatever state is causing it, and your workaround seems fine. I would use `if (php_last_error())` to check whether `json_decode()` got an error.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. It's not the end of the world if I have to use json_encode, but it would be nice if there was some other way.

Answer (score -1):

I downgrade the version to V4.1.5, It works.

> "name": "pusher/pusher-php-server", "version": "v4.1.5",